# How to change HTML in servlet page?

Tags: java, xml, servlets, jakarta-ee

So, i want have a servlet something like this

[image]

But my page looks like this

[image]

Here my web.xml

[image]

Comment: Better you post the actual code instead of images of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the content type to `text/html`

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

what you have is

```
response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
```

Hence the browser treating it as text.

Comment: Thanks mate, i dont know why i type there plain :O.

Comment: No problem. Learn jsp next :)